# Double integral, calculate area of surface.

Tags: integration

Calculate the conical surface:
$$ 3z^2 = x^2 + y^2,\quad\quad (0 ≤ z ≤2)  $$ I understand that to calculate ds i need to do partial integration as so:

$$  6z{\partial z\over\partial x}=2x,\quad\quad 6z{\partial z\over\partial x}=2y  $$
which can be rewritten as:

$$  {\partial z\over\partial x}={x\over3z},\quad\quad {\partial z\over\partial y}={y\over3z}$$

Now we have enough information to calcuate the ds

$$ ds = \sqrt{1 +{x^2+y^2\over 9z^2}}da \quad=\quad\sqrt{{9z^2+3z^2\over 9z^2}} = {2\sqrt3\over3} ={2\over\sqrt3}  $$

Now here is where i have a bit of a problem with the solution manual. The solution manual tells me to write the integral as such:

$$ \int\int_{x^2 + y^2≤12} {2\over\sqrt3} da $$

I understande that i need to integrate this: $${2\over\sqrt3}$$

But i don't get where the limit  comes from and why 12? and how is it rewritten to a normal limit form?

What i need help with is for someone to explain why it's less than or equal to 12, i think it's because z = 2 and that 3*2^2 = 12. But i may be wrong, anyway... The solution to this is:
$$ {24\pi\over\sqrt3}$$

I also don't understand where pi comes from, i am guessing that the limit is a circular such, but then shouldn't it be 2pi?

Comment: At the top you say you have to calculate the surface area of part of a cone, but the equation you gave to define the conical surface actually describes a paraboloid, not a cone. Cones are instead described by equations of the form $a^2\color{#ff0000}{z^2} = x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: You are right, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are many ways to compute the surface area of a cone. From  the given hint I assume that the following heuristic is intended:

Your cone $C$ is given as a rotational surface that projects injectively onto the $(x,y)$-plane. Each surface element of $C$ includes the same angle with a horizontal plane; therefore the area dilatation of the projection is constant, namely $\sqrt{3}/2$ when projecting down and its reciprocal when "projecting up" (you found this out, somehow). It follows that the area of $C$ is $2/\sqrt{3}$ times the area of its shade $C'$ in the $(x,y)$-plane. Since $x^2+y^2=12$ along the upper rim of $C$ it follows that $C'$ is a disk of radius $\sqrt{12}$. All in all we obtain
$${\rm area}(C)={2\over\sqrt{3}}\>\pi\bigl(\sqrt{12}\bigr)^2={24\pi\over\sqrt{3}}\ .$$